# Change values in an object to be snake cased

Tags: java

I have the following data stored as an Object.

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "name",
        "titles": [
            [
                "valueOne",
                "valueTwo"
            ],
            [
                "somethingElse"
            ],
            [
                "anotherValue",
                "someValue"
            ],
            [
                "myValue"
            ],
            [
                "aValue",
                "theValue"
            ]
        ]
    },
}
```

What would be the cleanest way to convert all the values from camel case to snake case?

Meaning change `valueOne` to `value_one` and so on.

Was trying to use `ObjectMapper` but looks like it is only for use for keys, not values.

Tried the following. But end up with no diff or incorrect structure. Pls help.

```
// makes no difference when this is done. 
Map<String, Object> myLayout = (Map<String, Object>) data.getMyLayout();
List<List<String>> titles = (List<List<String>>) myLayout.get("titles");
titles.forEach(titleList -> titleList.forEach(title -> CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, title)));


// this changes the structure incorrectly. Should maintain list of list of String. 
Map<String, Object> myLayout = (Map<String, Object>) data.getMyLayout();
List<List<String>> titles = (List<List<String>>) myLayout.get("titles");

List<String> updatedTitles = titles.stream()
        .flatMap(title -> title.stream()
                .map(name -> CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, name))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
myLayout.put("titles", updatedTitles);
```

Incorrect structure based on above implementation.

```
"myLayout": {
    "name": "name",
    "titles": [
        "value_one",
        "value_two",
        "something_else",
        "another_value",
        "some_value",
        "my_value",
        "a_value",
        "the_value"
    ]
},
```

Ultimately looking to achieve this.

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "name",
        "titles": [
            [
                "value_one",
                "value_two"
            ],
            [
                "something_else"
            ],
            [
                "another_value",
                "some_value"
            ],
            [
                "my_value"
            ],
            [
                "a_value",
                "the_value"
            ]
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: You're not far off, but if you want to preserve the nesting, don't use `flatMap`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I ended up using a flatmap cos without it I end up with a List<Stream<String>> instead of a List<String>.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by performing the following, using a map instead of flatmap and collecting the internal mapped data first before collecting the outer list.

```
Map<String, Object> myLayout = (Map<String, Object>) data.getMyLayout();
List<List<String>> titles = (List<List<String>>) myLayout.get("titles");

List<String> updatedTitles = titles.stream()
        .map(title -> title.stream()
                .map(name -> CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, name))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
myLayout.put("titles", updatedTitles);
```